# Define ring bond length in chemfig

Tags: chemfig

How can one define the bond length for a ring system in chemfig? `**6(-[,0.5]-[,0.5]-[,0.5]-[,0.5]-[,0.5]-[,0.5])` does not work, sadly.

EDIT:

The answer provided resizes the ring system, but not the circle within it, *on my system*. Here's my configuration:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[landscape, top=0.3cm, left=0.1cm, right=0.3cm, bottom=0.3cm]{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{letterpaper}                   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig, chemmacros}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: Do you only want a smaller benzene or is the smaller benzene part of a larger molecule where the rest has it's original size?

Comment: I want a smaller one. I'm looking to insert molecules inline with text.

Comment: Please, if you use `mhchem` for your chemical formulas and also use `chemmacros` load the latter with `\usepackage[method=mhchem]{chemmacros}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the bond length at the begining of the ring:

```
\chemfig{A-*6([,0.5]------)}
```

gives a ring with half lengthed bonds.

EDIT: this work also with `**n` syntax.
For example

```
\chemfig{A-**6([,0.5]------)} \chemfig{A-**6(------)}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Oh nice. But then the circle doesn't change size :/ I'm using the `**n` syntax.

Comment: It also work with `**n` syntax (see edit in my previous post)

Comment: Hmm.. It doesn't work in my case. Weird!

Comment: Why don't you post a mwe?

Comment: If you meant I should provide my LaTeX configuration, I have done so!

Comment: A mwe is a Minimal Working Example. Your preamble is not the most important here.Just post the code of your molecule (which does not work). But before that, check you have the latest version of chemfig.